# what is the best way to show a multiple images in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I have a multiple images about 600 image I want to use it for page in viewPager. I put it all in drawable but it's take space what is the best way to store image?

Comment: why don't you get image from server? If you don't have server use firebase storage

Comment: use firebase database or store it in your local storage

Comment: You should use some cloud server to host the images

Comment: If you don't want to do the hassle of setting-up a server, don't want to use Firebase cloud storage then you can use free image uploading websites like Imgur. You can add images on it without creating a account (though account will give you access to manage them) and you can also keep these images hidden from public by clicking on hidden button and copying the URL of every image. Maintain a database of URLs of these images and use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)/[Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) to load them with URL. Easy-peasy.

Comment: @LalitFauzdar Imgur doesn't seem to work on some devices, whereas Discord does the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uploading them to a Cloudstorage (or Discord) and then loading the images with their links using Coil or Glide would be a way.

As a **Kotlin**-User [Coil](https://github.com/coil-kt/coil/) is the way to go. It's very lightweight, for additional functionalities (like animating Gifs, loading SVGs) take a look [here](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/getting_started/).

Dependency:

```
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil:1.2.1")
```

Load image from Url (trailing Lambda is optional):

```
imageView.load(imageUrl){
crossfade(true)
placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
transformations(CircleCropTransformation())
}
```

If You only have one Imageview per Page inside your Viewpager, You might create an Array with all the Urls given and then load them like so:

```
private var pageChangeCallback = object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
    override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
         imageView.load(image_urls[position])
     }
 }
```

---

If you prefer using **Java**, then go for [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide):

Dependency:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
```

Load image from Url (the options are optional):

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
                    .centerCrop()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
                    .error(R.drawable.error);

 Glide.with(this).load(image_url).apply(options).into(imageView);
```

Load the image whenever another page is selected.

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
     override void onPageSelected(int position) {
     Glide.with(this).load(image_urls[position]).apply(options).into(imageView);
     }
 }
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: If I want the user can see the image when he is not connected to the Internet is this way working without internet?

Comment: Can I storage it in a local database

Comment: @Ab898 i fear not. I'd recommend https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7876-android-file-grouping/ to group your drawable then or create some asset folder and sort them in there.

Comment: But note that this will take up quite a lot of storage on the user's device. Google Cloudstorage might be a valid option then.

Comment: @pentexnyx I'm using this way with coil to load 190 pic from url and show in recycler view adapter. but when scroll recycler , sometimes got this error : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Could not allocate JNI Env at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get those images would be storing those images in some server and fetching it using image libraries like `Glide`, `Picasso`, etc.

This way your app size won't increase and user experience would be good.

Here is how you can use `Glide` for this:

**Add the dependencies in build.gradle(app)**

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
}
```

**Using Glide to fetch the images**

```
ImageView targetImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);  
String internetUrl = "http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png";

Glide  
    .with(context)
    .load(internetUrl)
    .into(targetImageView);
```